# Java Client cancelling thread in REST

Tags: java, multithreading, rest

I wanted to cancel the REST thread triggered from client, however as REST should be stateless, how can this be achieved?

Comment: What is a "REST thread"?

Comment: I mean when my application started a UI process to get REST api and triggered a long running proccess from it, I can cancel that request from my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel the request on the server side, just return a response.
In case you want to kill the thread that is currently doing REST request, just kill the thread.

REST is stateless means that the web server does not store any state about the client application/session state. The session is stored on the client. The server is stateless means that every server can service any client at any time, there is no session affinity or sticky sessions. The relevant session information is stored on the client and passed to the server as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I think my comment a bit ambigious. I mean I wanted to cancel both the request thread and also the thread that is processing the request in REST server side.

Comment: Once you cancel the request, the server will not receive anything in the socket and will probably close (or abort) the connection (it could be different scenarios for different web servers like Tomcat, IIS, Jetty and etc.).

Comment: I have been searching around to look for a solution. One closest example will be http://shengwangi.blogspot.sg/2015/09/asynchronous-spring-mvc-hello-world.html , but unfortunately for my application I would need to have control from the client (another application) to invoke a cancel request to a previous request, and this have to go through REST api. My application doesn't have any information on the invoked thread over the REST api side, any advice?

Comment: Why not use timeout? The REST request will be canceled automatically because of timeout that you can define both on client and server. Once you cancel the REST API call in the application, the server will drop it as well, if not because of nothing received in the socket, then because of the timeout.

Comment: something worth considering in my use case. Thanks @Gen4ik.