# How to stop execution of method called from run() method of thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my Thread:-

```
Thread t=new Thread(){
  public void run(){
      downloadFile();
  }
}
t.start();

public static void main(){
  t.interrupt();
}
```

Here `downloadFile()` is long running method (downloading file from server)
The issue is , even though  `t.interrupt()` is called downloadFile() method still keeps running which is not expected . I want downloadFile() method to terminate immediately as soon as the thread is interrupted. How should i achieve it ?

Thanks.

EDIT1:

Here is downloadFile() skeleton which calls the rest API to fetch file:

```
void downloadFile(){
  String url="https//:fileserver/getFile"
  //code to getFile method  
}
```

Comment: So what does `downloadFile()` look like?

Comment: downloadFile() calls rest API to fetch the file from server.

Comment: How does it do that? You left out the most important code and provided trivial code that doesn't explain anything.

Comment: I think, this is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539800/java-client-cancelling-thread-in-rest

Comment: See here for additional info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425350/how-to-terminate-a-thread-blocking-on-socket-io-operation-instantly

Answer (score 0):

Your `Runnable` needs to store an `AtomicBoolean` flag to say whether it has been interrupted or not.

The `interrupt` method should just set the flag to true.

The `downloadFile()` method needs to check the flag **inside the download loop** and abort the download if it is set.

Something like this is the only clean way to implement it as only `downloadFile` knows how to safely and cleanly interrupt itself, closing sockets etc.

Comment: The problem is with the actual network operation. If there's a socket blocking on a read, the only surefire way to stop it is to close the socket. There's not necessarily any "download loop" (at least visible), unless he's writing raw network code himself. No need (or use) to duplicate the interrupt functionality either.

Answer (score -1):

You need some flag to inform a thread about termination:

```
public class FileDownloader implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public void terminate() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            try {
                downloadFile();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                running = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

in main:

```
FileDownloader fileDownloaderRunnable = new FileDownloader();
Thread thread = new Thread(fileDownloaderRunnable);
thread.start();
//terminating thread
fileDownloaderRunnable.terminate();
thread.join();
```

Comment: Presumably the method `downloadFile()` downloads a single file fully. Your loop would therefore download the file over and over again until you stop it. That doesn't really make sense.